# How to configure postfix to test site on LAMP virtualhost?

Tags: lamp, postfix

i want to test e-mail functions of php forum script.
I installed LAMP, postfix.

How to configure postfix to test e-mail from site on localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install and access webmin http://www.webmin.com/
2. If it is a virtual machine change the network mode to NAT to access internet or make sure your LAMP machine has internet access
3. Install Dovecot service. It will be our entry IMAP/POP3 mail server

   **by just searching in webmin you can install Dovecot**
4. Install BIND DNS service.

**Configure the DNS server**

1. First. We created the "Master Zone": miempresa.com and configure the following **records**

   A: ServerMail.mydomain.com 192.168.10.2

   MX: mydomain.com  ServerMail.mydomain.com (10)

   Create the "inverse area" of the previous domain
2. When resolving a name ask a DNS server of the Internet, for example in 8.8.8.8

**SMTP server settings**

1. First create user 'mailuser1'  with password 'a' group 'users'
2. Postfix server > Configuration of general options:

   What domain name to use for outgoing mail: mydomain.com

   What domain name to use for incomming mail: mydomain.com

   Send outgoing mail by machine: Deliver directly

   Number of machines of this Internet mail system: Default

   local networks: 127.0.0.0 / 8, 192.168.10.0/24
3. Test that its working. We can do it from Webmin > Servers > Reading Usuarios mails

   just send an email to your email and check that you receive, you may be spam.